# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray

Tags: json, eclipse

I have developed a sample Dynamic+Maven web project in Eclipse Mars.
I have written a servlet to accept a request and return a JSON. 
I run this application using Run As >> Run on server >> J2EE Preview at Local host option
I am running this application from Mozialla browser with the following url http://localhost:8080/ThirdServletProject/NewFile.htm

But I am getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray" error.

Following is the servlet code generating the above error

```
    private String getData() throws JSONException {

    String str = "";

    JSONArray cfArr = new JSONArray();      //This line generates error
    JSONObject cfObj = new JSONObject(); 
    cfObj.put("Name", "01/04/2016");
    cfObj.put("Country", "Interest");
    cfObj.put("Amount", 10000);
    cfArr.put(cfObj);
    str = cfArr.toString();
    return str;

}
```

Following is the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
<artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.json</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
<version>chargebee-1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Following is the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray
at com.servlet.AngularJsServlet.getData(AngularJsServlet.java:58)
```

I have tried all the solutions posted on the stackoverflow, but no luck.

1. project >> clean
2. tried different permutation & combinations in pom.xml
3. i have checked the .m2 folder for the json related libraries and they are present
4. Without using JSON the application works fine.

   ```
   String str = "[{\"Name\":\"John\", \"Country\":\"Doe\"}]";
   return str;
   ```
5. I have reinstalled Eclipse
6. Manually deleted the class files to make sure java classes are recompiled

All the options are exhausted, any new ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can some one please answer ?

Comment: I am surprised why no one is attempting my question ? I have provided all the details with the code. Anything wrong with my reputation ?

Comment: No one responded to my query, so I started my own R & D, but no luck. Coincidentally I created a new project & import all the classes, then it started working fine. Looks like bug in Eclipse.